# ОС на основе .NET Framework C#

Tags: .net

Как создать ОС на основе .NET Framework в которой можно было бы запускать приложения написанные на .NET?(Желательно WPF)

Comment: [Singularity (operating system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_\(operating_system\))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд на чистом .NET никак:

1. .NET целиком и полностью завязан на CLR, которая контролирует время жизни объектов. => что бы начать писать ОС, нужно написать свою CLR на неуправляемом языке.
2. .NET сам по себе проигрывает по производительности по сравнению с нативными языками, а ОС должна быть высокопроизводительной => опять же придется много работать с нативными языками.

Как видите, будут обязательно примесь в виде других языков.